# PHP To Run SQL Server Query

Tags: php

I have the below syntax (of course with the proper credentials in play) but the requested info is never shown on screen, nor an error thrown.  What should I alter in this syntax in order to have it function as required?

What I am after, is on the button click event, to run the query and echo the result on screen.

```
<?php
if ($_POST['productname']) 
{ 
    mysql_connect('SERVER', 'user', 'password'); 
    mysql_select_db('database'); 
    $query = "Select Top 1 [EmpName] FROM [Server].[dbo].[Table]";
    $result = mysql_query($query); 
    echo $result[0]; } ?>
 <form id="form1" method="post">
<div style="padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 40px; width: 650px;">Start Date: <input type="date" name="startdate" /> End Date: <input type="date" name="enddate" />
<div style="padding-top: 10px;"><button id="btnSubmit" name="productname" type="button">Submit</button></div>
<div style="padding-top: 10px;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</form>.
```

Comment: why do you use mYsql_connect to connect to mSsql?

Comment: that sql syntax looks like SQL Server, but you're trying to use MySQL. You also shouldn't use mysql_ since it's depreciated. Replace it with mysqli_

Comment: @A.Zheng - I do want to use MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the result of query you have to **SUBMIT** form with button like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp). 
If you want to do this without reload, you have to use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or AJAX with JS or [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/). 
To sum up:

- Add submit button.
- Make your form submit with php or ajax according to your goals.

Comment: using ajax can I do it all in one document like I showed above?  Every example I see shows to use  `url:'your url here'`

Comment: Yes, you do.
Just add `<script>` tag and write your JS code with ajax. Put listener to your submit button with JS or jQuery, choose what will be easier for you to use, like this https://api.jquery.com/click/ and then execute ajax script on click.